# Suppress "Problems" (on scss) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, sass, visual-studio-code

I have the following lines in my scss project:

```
:host /deep/ .image-img {
    height: 60pt;
}
```

This syntax is [fine in my context](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html), and the will compile. I don't believe there is any support/extension for this syntax in VSCode. So Visual Studio Code tries to be helpful and points out the following problems:

> [scss] { expected ('18,7')
>
> [scss] at-rule or selector expected (20,1)

I can just ignore these. After all, it does compile and it only shows these errors while the file is open. I do like all the other help that VSO Code gives me when writing scss, so I'm not goign to disable it entirely.

However, **is there a way to ignore complier problems for certain lines**? Eg in a similar way to `/* tslint:enable */` for ts-lint. Is there maybe some other way I can enjoy the benefits of VSCode code's checking of my scss, but also get rid of these erroneous errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/deep/ is deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

If you want to use it anyway, the alias **`::ng-deep` works better** with Visual Studio Code, as it fits into the CSS pseudo element format.